# Editing a question I affect the answer that made me edit

Tags: discussion

I post a question with an example, and that example make an user post an answer that fix that particular example, but not the real question because I do not specified it in the question, so I want to change the example to avoid future confusion and be more specific about the case that the answerer gave but if I do that his answer would be wrong and even would be meaningless because that would be specified in the question.

This is my question [How can I make transition property work in IE by using calc properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605163/how-can-i-make-transition-property-work-in-ie-by-using-calc-properties)

The Sergey's answer fix my example but the problem is that I do not know where the bottom will be, I just put it to the end as an example, but I really do not know where it'll be.

I want to specify the above mentioned and provide a new example.

So what should I do

-Provide a new example and to specify the case in a comment in his answer?

-Edit the question and notify answerer?

-Anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the question or add unrelated comments, **ask a new question**. You can always include a link to the original question if you think it would help.

If you change the question so it invalidates the answers(s) then such a change is likely to be rolled back as you've

- made the answers seem like nonsense which exposes them to unjustified future downvotes
- wasted the time of the answerers and also future readers of the question and its answers(s)

Comment: Would you not tag it as duplicate?, because it is the same question with a not very different example and specification

Comment: @YandYViera Explain in the question exactly why it is not a duplicate then.